# how to implement access control using connetcing hostname and port(squid)

Tags: proxy, http, squid

some http proxy service providers here just assign an unique proxy address and port to a user, and the user just needs to enter the necessary proxy address and port to get access.I think this method is superior to username and password authentication, and also,this makes it possible to proxy a lot of mobile apps on ios devices and android which don't support traditional proxy authentication. i found they are using squid for caching and proxying. can squid alone achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, squid will answer on as many ports as you would like; just add them into its configuration.

The problem with this approach is that there is no access control; *anyone* who manages to find the IP address and port can then use (or more likely, abuse) the proxy.

Comment: you also need the correct hostname for example,4545454.proxy.com. the prefix number part is used to authenticate together with port number.

Comment: How would that be used for authentication? The hostname _of the proxy_ is never sent to it.

Comment: i don't know. but i tried using the resolved ip address and the port to authenticate and it failed. the hostname is different for every user.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain in more detail exactly how these proxies work. It sounds like they are not "normal" proxies.

Comment: i don't know how they exacty work.i just tried their service a few days ago, and the hostname and port is the only credentials i get for accessing their server. After i entered the proxy address and port number in network setting in my android phone,almost all internet traffic are routed through the proxy. no authentication windows pops up when i browser the internet. if i visited a incorrect domain, the squid standard error page will come up, and that's when i know they are using squid.